# Is rebuilding a website considered plagiarism?

Tags: legal

Our company has a website hosted and created by some company but we don't like the way things are handled so we decided to pull the plug and create & host our own website.

Now the question is:

**Is rebuilding this website from scratch (so using nothing of the original code, but looking and functioning the same) considered plagiarism/illegal?**

Can the original designing/hosting company sue us or anything if they saw we "took" their website? Even if we can prove we have written it ourselves?

Comment: If I were you, before doing this I would ask myself: Will this site bring an added value to the visitors? If yes, I would do it, if no, I would thing one more time and try to look at the situation from another point.

Comment: @Marian - yes it will. Sometimes we have to wait up to 2 weeks(!) for changing something simple, while having it in our own management would only take max 2 days. The communication with them was terrible and the way they handled customers (us) isn't quite *nice*..

Comment: What kind of contract have you? The usual case is that you pay them for creating the website, and then you are free to host it where you want, and make any changes to the site/design you want.

Comment: @unor - it's under their management and hosting with their own CMS, we cannot access the server code. Changes **have** to be done by them.

Comment: @GeenHenk: That might be the current situation, but (depending on your actual contract) you might have the right to get a copy of the site (e.g., as static site, so "only" the content and the design, not the CMS) and host it elsewhere.

Comment: legal questions have different answers in different jurisdictions.  I suggest you tell us where you are, where the hosting company is, and under what jurisdiction the contract is executed if that's defined by the contract.

Comment: It is issues such as this that is making me want to go to law school. I am semi-retired from the IT industry and I see people get hosed all the time with hosting companies, developers, and with copyright. It just plain p15535 me off! It is reasonable that you own some portion of the work since you requested it and paid for it. The reasonable man standard mandates quid pro quo in any agreement. Often contracts will contain clauses that are illegal or will not hold up in court and the clause will be thrown out. Many contracts that fail this standard are null and voided by the courts.

Comment: Be careful about getting crowdsourced legal advice. I think a lot of what is said here is sensible and may well hold up, but if I were you I would consult a professional. An hour of advice now may save a long battle later - and perhaps a well worded (lawyer's) letter to the current creating/hosting company will be all you need to safely move on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This completely depends on your contract.  If you have a contract with them stating they will build a website and manage it for you, but they retain the rights, then no you can not rebuild it.  There are two separate issues.  One is the code to build the website, and one is the design.

It is the **Design** related **contract** that determines if you can rebuild with your own code but make the design the same.  If they own the rights to the design, for example, a well known design firm that lets you 'license' their design while under contract, you will not be allowed to use that same design.  If however, they have sold you the **design** during the purchase, you are free to do with it as you like.

Comment: The design is ours, our graphic designer team has designed it, their webdevelopers "just" made it show. Whose design is it then?

Comment: It is your design.  They made one implementation of it.  You can make your own.

Comment: BTW- These types of contracts where the developer holds the rights to the work primarily related to content and not design and function, does not hold up in court. It would be disallowed by any judge under the reasonable man standard. It is reasonable to pay for expertise and assistance in design and function, but not reasonable to own a companies identity, marketing, and content resulting from such a contract.

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me (designer/coder/hoster) before – and will happen again. My approach always was that it's *of course* sad to see clients go, but *of course* it's ok if they take **their** website with them. And if that means they want to re-write the code but keep the layout I rather feel flattered, than angry.

So my point of view is that **your** website is **your** website – even if they designed and built it. It might be concidered unpolite if you'd change logo, layout, design or even changing the cms without first talking to them.

That said you should probably **first** try to talk to the company that created and hosted your website. Tell them you want to move and take your website with you – and ask them if they have any problem with that or doubts about it. Sooner or later they would find out anyways.

ps: naturally I would answer your question "*Is rebuilding someone else's website considered plagiarism?*" with 'yes'. But since it's **your** website things are a bit more complex. So I would recomment you leave out the "someone else's" and shorten your question to "*Is rebuilding a website considered plagiarism?*". The shortened question in the context you described I would answer with 'No'.

Comment: That's the thing, **when** they find out that we've been rebuilding the site - pulling the plug, cancelling the contract, relocating the domain name, setting our rebuilt website online - will *that* have consequences?

Comment: Can't vote down, but this misses the core issue: contracts. It's not about 'your' website or 'their' website, it's about who owns the rights to what. **Only** if the copyright has been explicitly transferred for a work can it be 'yours'. In this case the OP's company made the design themselves, so that's clearly theirs. If the contract transferred the copyright of the code to them then that's theirs as well. If not however then the OP can not even use the HTML of the webpage in the process of rebuilding the site!

Comment: In general I have seen especially bigger clients requesting that code be shared (which is a bit harder contractually if you use your own proprietary frameworks), so they get a license to their own code and bla bla bla (I didn't write up the legal construction, but apparently it keeps both us and our clients happy :P ).

Comment: Depending on the law in your jurisdiction, it might be the case that because it is commissioned work, the copyright is yours by default unless that's modified by contract.

Comment: I agree @David Mulder – it's a question of contracts. Usually you qould have the right to use the 'design' (logo, ci etc.) for your website – no matter what cms you use. So that would not be plagiarism, but correct use of the art work – as long as you don't alter it or 'recycle' the webdesign for print use etc... BUT of course it might be different in your case – but imho that only you and the design/hosting company can know.

Comment: @DavidMulder Just because something is written in a contract, does not make it legal. There are plenty of developers that try and control all of their work and hi-jack it for personal gain. This never holds up in court. The reasonable man standard mandates quid pro quo in any agreement and it is reasonable that the person paying the bill owns some reasonable portion of the work. This is often tied to content, identity, and marketing and not function and specific expertise. I have been through some cases like this. Do not assume that a contract gives you rights. It does not always.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your plagiarism question, since the website is yours there should be no issue. Copyright in the content does not transfer to the hosting company simply because they have provided a means to publish the content. If they have written all the website text, taken all the photos and designed all the corporate branding logos/graphics by themselves then you might have an issue since the Copyright by default sits with the author of the work unless transferred in a contract. Have you read through their terms and conditions of business?

---

On a side-note to address your concern relating to the consequences of terminating the contract as indicated in your comment to @tillinberlin:

If you are not sure how the news of terminating the contract with your web hosting company will go, and you don't trust them to behave honourably in releasing a copy of your website or ensuring the transfer to another host provider goes smoothly, then you should:

1. Secure the **domain name**. If you registered it yourself then you probably have login details to be able to update the registrant (owner) details and change the name-servers, special DNS records that tell everyone on the Internet how to find the server(s) your website is hosted on. If your current hosting company registered this name originally, then you will need to:

   (a) Check via a [WHOIS query](http://who.is/) that it is registered with your name or your company name as the official registrant, and not their company name or someone else's name. If this needs changing then approach this and get it sorted prior to any discussion about terminating their contract. Asking for login details to your domain or asking to transfer your domain name away to another registrar will be a red flag event for them unfortunately so it is always best practice in my opinion to keep domain name registration with a separate company to the one who hosts your website - try to ignore deals such as get a free domain with your hosting!;

   (b) Check that you have *exclusive* login access to control the domain name on the registrar's (companies that sell domain names) website. Do your login details work? If not get the password reset and make sure you can login, and that noone else has the password. Check that there are no additional users setup to access the domain using email addresses other than your own, remove them if there are!;
2. Secure a **static copy of the website**. While it is certainly a pain to have to redo your website an incorporate a new CMS, and SEO can go horribly wrong with all the URL changes, if you have a static copy of the website setup and hosted with your new hosting company then you can change the name-servers to point to their servers, even before they've started working on a new version, and while your current hosting company doesn't even know you will be terminating the contract. [WinHTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) is an excellent free tool for taking a static copy of your website.
3. To rescue your SEO and ensure all your users don't end up reaching *HTTP 404 Not Found* error pages by clicking on Search Engine search results links, get your new hosting company to setup HTTP 301 redirects for all the URL's that will no longer work and point them towards the newly copied static version of the page (ending in .html). In the unlikely event your CMS used the .html extension on all the URLs you may be able to skip this step, but it is unlikely.

Comment: The domain name is ours, the design is ours, just the code isn't. Thanks this made it a lot clearer.

Comment: Having had an experience like this and having had to rebuild an originally CMS-based site back into a dynamic website manually, I now keep clear of any hosting company that promotes or uses their own CMS. Keeping CMS vendor and hosting company separate helps ensure your site can be moved to any hosting company. Changing from one CMS to another CMS is always a big job, so you either want a CMS that is free but very well supported or affordably commercially licensed with excellent support.